# Recording front and back camera at the same time

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ioexception

My app crashes with this error message. I don't know how to set the outputfile for this code.please help me correcting my code. I am very new to android.

I/FrontAndBackCamera: Prepare failed
I/System.out: java.io.IOException: No valid output file
I/FrontAndBackCamera: Start Recording

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
enter code here
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dual_cam);
    recordBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);
    recordBtn.setOnClickListener(recordVideoListener);

    Log.i(TAG,"Number of cameras:" + Camera.getNumberOfCameras());
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},CAMERA);
    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG,"Already have the permission");

        mBackCamera=getCameraInstance(0);

        BackCameraPreview mBackCamPreview = new BackCameraPreview(this, mBackCamera);
        FrameLayout backPreview=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_camera_preview);
        backPreview.addView(mBackCamPreview);

        mFrontCamera=getCameraInstance(1);
        FrontCameraPreview mFrontCamPreview = new FrontCameraPreview(this, mFrontCamera);
        FrameLayout frontPreview=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_camera_preview);
        frontPreview.addView(mFrontCamPreview);
        Log.i(TAG,"about to call prepare to record video...");
        prepareToRecordVideo();
    }

}
public void prepareToRecordVideo()
{
    //start recording stuff
    Log.i(TAG,"PREPARE TO RECORD VIDEO");
    mBackCamera.unlock();
    mFrontCamera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder1.setCamera(mBackCamera);
    mediaRecorder2.setCamera(mFrontCamera);

    mediaRecorder1.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder1.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder1.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mediaRecorder1.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mediaRecorder1.setOutputFile(this.initFile("CAMERA_1_").toString());

    sft=new SurfaceTexture(0);
    sf=new Surface(sft);

    mediaRecorder1.setPreviewDisplay(sf);
    mediaRecorder1.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
            Log.i(TAG,"RECORDING FAILED ERROR CODE:"+i+"AND EXTRA CODE:"+i1);
        }
    });
    CamcorderProfile cp=CamcorderProfile.get(1,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mediaRecorder2.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder2.setOutputFormat(cp.fileFormat);
    mediaRecorder2.setVideoEncoder(cp.videoCodec);
    mediaRecorder2.setVideoEncodingBitRate(cp.videoBitRate);
    mediaRecorder2.setVideoFrameRate(cp.videoFrameRate);
    mediaRecorder2.setVideoSize(cp.videoFrameWidth,cp.videoFrameHeight);
    mediaRecorder2.setOutputFile(this.initFile("CAMERA_2_").toString());

    sft2=new SurfaceTexture(0);
    sf2=new Surface(sft2);

    mediaRecorder2.setPreviewDisplay(sf2);
    mInitSuccesful=true;
    Log.i(TAG,"RECORD INIT SUCCESSFUL"+ mInitSuccesful);
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(requestCode){
        case CAMERA:
        {
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mBackCamera=getCameraInstance(0);
                mFrontCamera=getCameraInstance(1);
                Log.i(TAG,"about to call prepareToRecordVideo...");
                prepareToRecordVideo();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
private View.OnClickListener recordVideoListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (recording) {
            mediaRecorder1.stop();
            mediaRecorder1.reset();

            mediaRecorder2.stop();
            mediaRecorder2.reset();

            recording = false;
            recordBtn.setText("Start Recording");
            Log.i(TAG, "Stop Recording");
        } else {
            //start recording
            try {
                mediaRecorder1.prepare();
                mediaRecorder2.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Prepare failed");
                System.out.println(""+e);
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException e){
                Log.i(TAG, "Start Recording cam1");
                mediaRecorder1.start();

                Log.i(TAG, "Start Recording cam2");
                mediaRecorder2.start();
            }
            recording = true;
            recordBtn.setText("Stop Recording");
            Log.i(TAG, "Start Recording");
        }
    }
};

private File initFile (String cameraNamePrefix)
{
    File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"FrontAndBackCamera");
    if(!dir.exists()&& !dir.mkdirs())
    {
        Log.wtf(TAG,"Failed to create storage directory:"+dir.getAbsolutePath());
        Toast.makeText(this, "not record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        file=null;
    }
    else{
        String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile=new File(dir.getPath()+File.separator+cameraNamePrefix+timeStamp+".mp4");
        Log.i(TAG,mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return mediaFile;
    }
    return file;
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(int cameraId)
{
    Camera camera =null;
    try{
        camera=Camera.open(cameraId);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Camera" + cameraId+"is not available"+e.toString());
    }
    return camera;
}
```